# having issues with simple for loop program. the similar code is having completely different results

Tags: loops, for-loop, factorial

I am a beginner programmer. i have just started learning c++. I am currently trying to find project which will help me in practicing different types of loop and command statements. in my recent project of creating a program to find factorial for a given number using for loop i am having problems which might be due to code differences. Can you guys help me find the differences in each code and why the outputs of each program are different ?
this is a code i wrote myself :

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (){
    int i,B;
// B=1;

    for (i=0; i < 10; i++);
    {
    //B*=i;                

    cout << i;
    //cout << B << endl;
}
}
```

the code above gives output of only 10

this is a code i copied

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int a;
    for (int a=1; a <=10;a++)
    {
    cout << a << endl ;
    }
}
```

this gives output of all the numbers upto 10.

i cant see any reason why the first code would give me an output of 10 as it is "<10" and not "<=10

Comment: The difference is the semicolon you added at the end of the `for` line. That semicolon separates your for loop from the subsequent lines.

Comment: thanks man, this has been puzzling me for quite a few minutes. It's really amazing that how much a misplaced semicolon can have an effect on your program.